# command to connect multiple controller in a single controller in a web app

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, web-applications

I am a new bee
I am working on a . net web app and I got a task to connect all the controller files in one new controller.
web app consists of 12 controller files and i want to connect them in one large controller file
which helps our project database to be more convinent .

Comment: The controllers should not contain any database specific code. Put all of your Db code in a Repository file and call the methods from your controllers. -- Do a search on "Repository Pattern".

Comment: which command can i use to call the methods form controllers ?

Comment: In your controller add a Using statement for the namespace of your repository then when you want to use it create a new instance and call it. --- This is the most simple way. You can also use dependency injection to get your instance of the repository.

Comment: so how should I call after creating a new instance ??

Comment: which command should i need to use ?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are trying to call different controllers from one single controller you can use switch case.
Call this main controller action from your html page with a special parameter(i.e ActionName) to perform diffferent actions according to their parameter value.**

```
 public ActionResult Actions(string ActionName)
            {
             switch (ActionName)
                {
                case:"Action1"
                return RedirectToAction("Action1", "Controller1", new { area = "", id =""});
                break;
                case:"action2"
                return RedirectToAction("Action2", "Controller2", new { area = "", id =""});
                break;
                }
                return View();
            }
```